# Edit table values using MongoDB MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mongodb

I have populated a table from a MongoDB database. I now want to edit the contents of the table and update it. The piece of code I am using is probably obsolete.

The Controller Code is:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    MongoServer objServer = MongoServer.Create("Server=localhost:27017");
    MongoDatabase objDatabse = objServer.GetDatabase("MVCTestDB");
    IMongoQuery query = Query.EQ("ID", id);
    UserModel user = objDatabse.GetCollection<UserModel>("Users").Find(query).SingleOrDefault();
    return View(user);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(UserModel um)
{
    MongoServer objServer = MongoServer.Create("Server=localhost:27017");
    MongoDatabase objDatabse = objServer.GetDatabase("MVCTestDB");
    IMongoQuery query = Query.EQ("ID", um.ID);

    IMongoUpdate  updateQuery = Update.Set("UserName", um.UserName).Set("Password", um.Password).Set("Email", um.Email).Set("PhoneNo", um.PhoneNo).Set("Address", um.Address);
    UserModel user = objDatabse.GetCollection<UserModel>("Users").Find(query).SingleOrDefault();
    objDatabse.GetCollection<UserModel>("Users").Update(query, updateQuery);
    return RedirectToAction("GetUsers");
}
```

The compiler is unable to recognise **MongoServer.Create**

Answer (score 0):

I gess you have wrong connection string format and wrong method. It should be:

```
MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/MVCTestDB").GetServer();
```

Comment: Its giving the same error "'MongoDB.Driver.MongoServer' does not contain a definition for 'Create'"

Comment: @subhrendu then try `var _server = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/MVCTestDB").GetServer();`

Comment: Hey thanks man :). It worked. Although its throwing warning that the method is obsolete and use new API instead